# php if empty skip action

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, is-empty

I have a form with field

```
<input type="file" name="file" size="100" value="">
```

if this field is empty I want to skip trying to upload the image (because there isnt one) and only update any information that has changed. If an image is present upload it and update the mysql database.

This code was only working if a new image was being uploaded. Added the `if(!empty` but now the `wrong file type` code is popping when the form field is left blank?

```
// connect to datebase
require "master.db.php";

if(!empty($_FILES['file']))
    {
      if ( file types )
          {
           // upload the file
          }
       else
          {
           // wrong file type
                 die;
           }
     }

else {
    // update other data in mysql database
    $sql="UPDATE `characters` SET test='test' WHERE ID='$id'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    // if successfully updated mysql.
       if($result){
          echo "<b>Update successful</b> <br />";
          echo "<a href='../test.html'>View result</a>";
          touch('../master.html');
          clearstatcache();
          }

        else {
             echo "Whoops: " . mysql_error(); ;
              }
    mysql_close();
    }
```

Comment: If you want to skip uploading the image if file is empty, shouldn't that first if statement be `if (! empty($_POST["file"]))` ? As it stands, it'll try to run the first chunk of code if there's nothing in $_POST["file"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
if(!$_FILES['file']){ 
     echo "file is empty" 
}
```

instead of

```
if(empty($_POST['file']))
```

---

finally

```
    if(!empty($_FILES['file'])){ 
     //file has something
    }
   else{
     //either file is empty or filed is not set
   }
```

Comment: Ok, the file was uploaded but the `$sql` didnt run, also trying to update other fields and leave "file" empty caused the `invalid file type` to pop

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php
  if(!empty($_FILES))
  {
    $name = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
    $type = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"];
    $size = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"];

    $match = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tb_name` WHERE file_name='$name'");
    if(!empty($match))
     {
       while($res=mysql_fetch_array($match))
       {
         if($type == "filetype")
           {
             //upload
           }
         else
            //error
       }
     }
    else
      //file already exists
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: I stripped a lot of code out of my question because the issue seems to be that regardless of the form filed being populated or not the starting `if(!empty` statement is not being followed. Is your answer to try restructuring the `if else` statements. Also where is the code that updates the sql date if the file field is not populated?